# why isn't nl2br() working

Tags: php, mysql, nl2br

I am trying to format $c (basically it is blocks of information that I need to appear in paragraph form). I am using nl2br() to introduce line breaks. So I have the following code:

```
   $search_output .= "*<i>$a</i>- <br/><b>field c: </b> $c <i>$b</i><br />";
 echo nl2br($c);
```

The problem is $c shows up twice.  Once as unformatted in $search_output and then formatted in echo nl2br(), but it pops up at the very top of the page and messes up my layout.

I want to merge nl2br($c) into $search_output.

I tried this:

```
$search_output .= "*<i>$a</i>- <br/><b>field c: </b> nl2br($c) <i>$b</i><br />";
```

It doesn't work.

**Please** help.  I am new at this.  And losing my mind.  nl2br() works separately, but I need the formatted content *as part* of $search_output.

Comment: If `nl2br()` _isn't not_ working, isn't that normal...? ;)

Comment: yeah sorry just realized the error...see? what I tell you...I am LOSING MY MIND ;(

Answer (score 1):

Stop the string, put the code, start the string again. And don't forget to concatenate.

```
$search_output .= "*<i>$a</i>- <br/><b>field c: </b> " . nl2br($c) . " <i>$b</i><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

use the right syntax. Its an function/method and not an variable

```
 $search_output .= "*<i>$a</i>- <br/><b>field c: </b> " . nl2br($c) . " <i>$b</i><br />";
```